# Spine Location Min not working

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

So I have implemented a little epub reader for fixed layout format. In landscape mode, everything is working fine (with the UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid).

Now I am trying to fix the portrait mode, so naturally in my `- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {`

I set a single view controller instead of two and I return `return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;`

Now this simply does not work, the page view controller remains empty without anything inside it. The sad part is that if I return `return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMax;` instead, it does work!! But then the flip occurs from the wrong side...

Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have fixed my own problem moving this function

```
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:controllers
                                          direction:direction
                                           animated:YES
                                         completion:nil];
```

Into viewWillAppear instead of from spineLocationForOrientation...